# Laravel accessing one to one relationship from the views

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The code below one runs and the other doesn't. The code runs inside a foreach loop.
Does anyone know why the first one doesn't run?

```
{{ Status::find($workorder->statuses_id)->name }} //this doesn't


{{ Status::find(1)->name }} //this works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your relationship defined like this...

```
class Workorder extends Eloquent {

    public function status() {
        return $this->hasOne('Status');
    }
}
```

You would need to do:

```
{{ Status::find($workorder->status->id)->name }}
```

This works for me no issues.

Alternatively, if you want to use the syntax you originally provided you could define a method on the Workorder class like this:

```
public function getStatusesIdAttribute() {
    return $this->hasOne('Status')->first()->id;
}
```

...but that is a little awkward and likely not the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it to work thanks to you. One more thing before I check this off. Inside the foreach can I also access it like so $workorder->status_id->name is this possible? I seem to be getting a Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Should be $workorder->status->name as long as there's a 'name' column in the statuses table!

Comment: That should work really? something is wrong with my model then. damn it!

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'statuses.workorder_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statuses` where `statuses`.`workorder_id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, )) It's giving me this error now. Why is it trying to find workorder_id in the statuses table... it should just be where id = ?

Comment: Which table has the foreign key? Do you have a status_id in the workorders table? I'm guessing the statuses table is just a list of statuses and each workorder has one of those statuses? If that's the case, you likely want a belongsTo relationship in the Workorder class rather than a hasOne.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate! You guess right it was a mistake on the relationship definition.